Issue with Discord bot after upgrading from Discord Version 1.7.3 to 2.3.2: Role function not working correctly
Recently, I updated my Discord bot from Discord Version 1.7.3 to the latest version, 2.3.2. However, after the update, the bot ceased to function as expected. I attempted to resolve the issue by setting intents to discord.Intents.all() and intents.message_content = True, but the problem persists. I'm relatively new to Discord bot development and I'm struggling to understand what's causing this issue.
My code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from decouple import config

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot("!", intents=intents)

class Reactions(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        message_id = payload.message_id  

        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        emoji = payload.emoji

        guild = self.bot.get_guild(guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)


        elif message_id == ADD message ID:
            role = None
            if str(emoji) == "":
                role = guild.get_role(ID role)
            elif str(emoji) == "":
                role = guild.get_role(ID role)
                # second_role = guild.get_role(ID role)
            elif str(emoji) == "":
                role = guild.get_role(ID role)
            if role is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)

        elif message_id == ADD message ID:
            role = None
            if str(emoji) == "":
                role = guild.get_role(ID role)
            elif str(emoji) == "":
                role = guild.get_role(ID role)
            elif str(emoji) == "":
                role = guild.get_role(ID role)
            if role is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)

bot.add_cog(Reactions(bot))

TOKEN = config("TOKEN")
bot.run(TOKEN)

In an attempt to solve the problem, I made adjustments to the code to include intents = discord.Intents.all() and intents.message_content = True. I was expecting this to address any issues related to changes in the Discord.py versions. However, even after these adjustments, the bot still isn't functioning correctly.

Considering "Python 1.7.3" has never existed, and Python "2.3.2" was released in October 2003, I am doubtful that this is the case. Can you edit your question to clarify what you're actually referring to?

I edited the message, it was due to lack of attention, but I was referring to the version of Discord that I installed

That can't be your only issue, Bot.add_cog is a coroutine from discord.py 2.0+ and it must be awaited.

Reference:
extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous


To solve this problem you just need to adjust the hierarchy of server positions. The code is right

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
